# animate css use it on a ngIf

Tags: ionic3, ng-animate, animate.css

I have a test button like this to check if everything is working okay:

```
<div animates #animation="animates" text-center>
   <button ion-button (click)="animation.start({type: 'fadeOutLeft', duration: '1000'})">Click me!</button>
</div>
```

But what I am trying to achieve is to set this animation on an `ngif` I want to make the first element disappear with the `fadeOutLeft` animation here below the code of the `ngIf`

```
<ion-scroll scrollX="true">
   <div *ngIf="!clicked">
     <div class="availability-btn-wrapper" *ngFor="let availableDaysBtn of availableDays" (click)="getDay(availableDaysBtn)">
        <button ion-button round outline>{{ availableDaysBtn }}</button>
     </div>
   </div>
   <div *ngIf="clicked">
       <div class="availability-btn-wrapper" *ngFor="let availableTimeBtn of availableTimes" (click)="getTime(availableTimeBtn)">
           <button ion-button round outline>{{ availableTimeBtn }}</button>
       </div>
   </div>
</ion-scroll>
```

I want to add this animation on the first `ngIf="!clicked"` that it disappears with that animation hope some one could help me out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Angular Animations provide you with nice transition hooks. For your case, if you want to animate div when it's gone you should register your animation on `:leave` hook. Then when the expression in `ngIf` is executed and specific HTML is about to be hidden animation registered on `:leave` will be executed.

[Check out this guide](https://angular.io/guide/animations),  and search for leave I mentioned above.